# What does squeeze = True do in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found doc says  reduce the dimensionality of the return type if possible,otherwise return a consistent type.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'a': np.ones(4, dtype='float32'),
     'b': np.ones(4, dtype='float32'),
     'c': np.zeros(4, dtype='float32')})

df.groupby(df4.index,squeeze=True)['b'].sum()
```

I couldn't see any change with or without squeeze.Can someone explain me the real purpose of squeeze = True and why is it by default set to false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of research it is used to reduce the dimension if possible. An example showed by @Jeff in github shows why exactly squeeze is used. Its stated in the issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3433).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = range(4), B = 0))

def func(dataf):
    return pd.Series({ dataf.name : 1})


result1 = df1.groupby("B",squeeze=False).apply(func)
   0
B   
0  1
type(result1)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

result2 = df1.groupby("B",squeeze=True).apply(func)

B   
0  0    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64

type(result2)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Squeeze will try to reduce the dimension if its possible to reduce. As you can see above dataframe can be reduced to series so it was done via squeeze parameter. There are very less cases of use of squeeze.

Comment: `squeeze` has become a common idiom. It is included as a param in `read_csv` (well, most I/O functions), and there's a function as well - `df.squeeze` which does the same thing. Very handy.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah, but usually squeeze in groupby had no effect as it was being done as usual. It was hard to find an example where squeeze plays a role based on the parameter in groupby.