# Pandas groupby when only one value groupedby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to compute the cumulative count of a given variable. So I expect that the following code works

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records({'x': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records({'x': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

result = df.groupby('x').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(len(x)), index=x.index)).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
assert (result == [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]).all()

result2 = df2.groupby('x').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(len(x)))).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
assert (result2 == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).all()
```

The first assert is True but not the second one.
Why ?

Comment: Calculate the cumulative counts by: `df.groupby('x').cumcount()`.

Comment: @ALollz, Agree, but it's still a valid question. I suspect there's some specific logic in Pandas internals which means one gives a series and the other a dataframe.

Comment: A bug I suppose.

Comment: Yeah it is the reason why `squeeze` parameter is implemented I think. You can check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298931/what-does-squeeze-true-do-in-groupby and the bug was reported here  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an open issue.

See [BUG: inconsistent return format of Dataframe group apply function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13056).

A workaround can be:

```
assert (result2.values == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).all()
```